# Deploy Bitbucket code to production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bitbucket, engineyard

My current code is in bitbucket. I have read methods to deploy the local code in server using `Dandelion and Capistrano gem`. But I donot want to deploy code directly to server, I mean I want to deploy code through bit bucket so that I can see the diff between local code and bitbucket code. Is there any method to deploy code from bitbucket using engine yard or something else? If yes, then please let me know.

Comment: May be this tutorial help you    https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/04/03/ruby-on-rails-deploy-on-engineyard-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you haven't read `Capistraino` in details. Actually you can use `Capistraino gem` to deploy code from your git repository to production server. See [this](http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2014/01/deploying-rails-apps-to-a-vps-with-capistrano-v3/) and [this](http://capistranorb.com/) for detail.